# Will offline progress on another system update trophies on my system or PSN account?

Tags: ps3

> Incidentally related:
>   [Transferring save games to a system without DLC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98220/6274)

I'm going to be spending the weekend at a friend's house.  I plan on taking some of my saved games off my PS3, and loading them on his, to work on.  However, I do not plan on logging in to PSN on his system and would rather avoid it unless it's necessary.  Still, I would like all my game progress (including trophies) to come home with me when I'm done.

I'd like to know whether or not I really *need* to log in to PSN on my friend's system, in order to have my earned trophies sync with my home system after I refresh the saved game.

To be clear, here's my current plan:

- My home system is always logged in to my PSN account.
- I will copy my saved games from my home system to a thumb drive, and load them on my friend's system.
- I will not log into my PSN account from my friend's system.
- I will *probably* end up earning some trophies while playing on my friend's system.
- After I'm done, I'll copy the updated save files from my friend's system back to my system via thumb drive.

Under these conditions, will the trophies earned while on my friend's system be transferred to my home system when I get back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **No. You probably will not earn trophies to your account**

In the situation you've described, where you use a save on an account where it wasn't created, will almost 100% make trophy earning ineligible, even if you copy it back to your system afterwards.

Your best option is to create another profile on your friend's system and log in to your PSN account, and on that account use your saves, this way you can ensure trophies will unlock. Make sure to sync your trophies when you log on to your profile for the first time and before leaving your friends house, so anything unlocked during your stay will transfer back to your account.