# Transferring save games to a system without DLC

Tags: ps3

> Incidentally related:
>   [Will offline progress on another system update trophies on my system or PSN account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98219/6274)

While I'm spending the weekend at a friend's house, I'd like to make some progress on some of my games.  However, my friend may not have a license for some of the DLC I have in those games.  Aside from missing some content, will this affect my ability to use my saved games on his system or return them to my system?

Comment: I think this answer depends on the games in question.
Another thing to consider is that you may need to log on to your PSN account to use your saves. If you do so, maybe you should just download the DLC to your friend's system as well and deactivate it afterwards, this way you don't have to worry about missing DLC and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the game. Certain games will warn you, often when first saving after either adding a DLC or after installing an update, that you won't be able to reload the save without the DLC. Disgaea 3 and 4 do this explicitly. You'd have to look and see for the specific game. If the DLC has anything to do with your save file (progess in the DLC is tracked or items are unlocked) it's probably not going to work without the DLC. If the DLC is something like a multiplayer map pack it *might* work without the DLC but I wouldn't assume.